# hive CLI hang "Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.3.0.0-2557/0/hive-log4j.properties"

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm working with HDP 2.3 and using hive CLI. However, it seems that Hive CLI hang when "Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.3.0.0-2557/0/hive-log4j.properties":

```
[root@sandbox ~]# hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1.2.3.0.0-2557-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/spark/lib/spark- assembly-1.3.1.2.3.0.0-2557-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.3.0.0-2557/0/hive-log4j.properties
```

Can anyone offer some pointer on how I might resolve this issue?

Comment: My environment used to work fine. The only thing I did is the installation of sqoop2. I'm not sure if this has nothing to do with my hive.

Comment: HortonWorks means you probably have TEZ by default, but it had no chance to pre-warm. Hmm. Wild guess: the **Metastore** is in a zombie state, accepting connections but not responding - and there's no timeout in these bloody Thrift clients. Did you try to browse the database & tables with Hue?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I didn't use Hue. I can see Tez jobs are being accepted but never get executed by ``yarn application -list`` and I guess yarn doesn't allocate enough resources for tez jobs but I don't know how to free the resources. Clearly, restart HDP doesn't help.

Comment: Any chance your install of Sqoop2 may have changed some global settings, e.g. weird default AppMaster memory requirements?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter That's a good question. I did run ``sqoop2-tool verify`` to verify the installation as the official manual suggest. Maybe this setup modify some global settings but I'm not sure.

Comment: I am facing similar issue, only difference is I had Sqoop installated at the time of setting up HDP itself. Hive cli doesnt come up since the start itself.